# AJAX Script that POSTS and GETS upon form submission

Tags: ajax, post, get

I'm working on a project where I'm attempting to POST a form submission to a db on one server then perform a GET action that sends the user to another site, which pre-populates a cart.  I've checked and the both the POST and GET functions work fine when isolated, but obviously you can't perform a GET and POST simultaneously on a standard form.  Upon researching here I found an AJAX example, but I've done very little AJAX in the past, below is what I have thus far, but it's not working right now, I'm not married to AJAX, if this can be done via javascript or php that's fine, any suggestions would be great, thanks!

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#fooform").on("submit", function(e) {
        $("#foobtnid").attr("style", "display: none;cursor: default");

        if ($("#foobtnid[type!='image']"))
        {
            $("#foobtnid").attr("style", "display: none;cursor: default;background-color: #B4B4B4");
            $("#waiting").text("Please wait...");
        }

        var data = $("#fooform :input").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "https://www.foositeone.com", 
            data: data, 
            success: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }, 
            error: function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET", 
            url: "https://www.foositewithpurchasepage.com", 
            data: data, 
            success: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }, 
            error: function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });


        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In what way is this not working?  You certainly can perform multiple simultaneous AJAX requests.  And I'm not sure what you mean by "if this can be done in JavaScript or PHP"... you might not be understanding what AJAX is.  You *are* doing this in JavaScript, and PHP can't execute in the browser.

Comment: The ajax is likely failing due to Same Origin Policy, If you have control of the other domains you can use CORS. If not you could submit forms to hidden iframes or use curl on the server side to submit the data.

Comment: @David it's not working in the sense that the POST function is passing through, but that's it, the GET function is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the the script was actually working however, because I'm going cross-server there's a security issue (see below), I ended up creating a work around within the store system with some direct add-to-cart links - and then employed some javascript to hide/show certain add to cart functions.

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foostoreurl. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://foolandingpage' is therefore not allowed access.
```